# Sign of dual variable in dual lagrange problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

When I consider a general minimization problem
\begin{align}
&\min f_0(\textbf{x})\\
&s.t \quad  g_i(\textbf{x}) \le 0 \qquad i=1,\dots ,p\\
& \qquad h_i(\textbf{x}) = 0 \qquad i=1,\dots ,m.
\end{align}

and consider the *primal* function $L(\textbf{x},\lambda,\nu)$, I would expect that the *dual* problem becomes something like this

\begin{align}
&\max g(\lambda,\nu)\\
&s.t \quad \lambda \le 0
\end{align}

(Since $\lambda$ is a vector, the inequality is intended componentwise), and $g$ is the dual function $g(\lambda,\nu) := \inf_{\textbf{x}} (L(\textbf{x},\lambda,\nu))$. I would expect this because I have a **minimization** problem with a $\le$ inequality constraints.

Why on **Convex Optimization** by Stephen Boyd, even if he clearly refers to a general problem of the form I put at the beginning, he says that in the dual problem we have $\lambda \ge 0$??

Comment: did you appreciate any of the answers?

Comment: You can find a very good explanation in this document: 
[https://cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

A cornerstone in the construction of the dual problem is the weak duality theorem. Let $f, q$ be the primal and dual problems (respectively). Then by weak duality $q^*\leq f^*$. To prove week duality, we define the primal set $$S=\{\mathbf{x}\in X: g_i(\mathbf{x})\leq 0, h_j(\mathbf{x})=0, i=1,\dots,m,\; j=1,\dots, p\}.$$ Then for any $(\lambda,\mu)\in\mathbb{R}^m_+\times\mathbb{R}^p$ we have
\begin{aligned} q(\lambda,\mu)&=\min_{\mathbf{x}\in X} L(\mathbf{x},\lambda,\mu)\\ 
&\leq \min_{\mathbf{x}\in S} L(\mathbf{x},\lambda,\mu) \\
&=\min_{\mathbf{x}\in S} \Big[f(\mathbf{x}) +\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i g_i(\mathbf{x})+\sum_{j=1}^p\mu_j h_j(\mathbf{x})\Big]\\
&\leq \min_{\mathbf{x}\in S} f(\mathbf{x})
\end{aligned}
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $\lambda_i\geq 0$ and $g_i(\mathbf{x})\leq 0$. If you change this, then you don't have weak duality anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Good for you that you do not just accept the theory, but try to link it to your previous knowledge on linear optimization.

In linear optimization, if you have $\min\{c^Tx : Ax \leq b\}$, the dual variable associated with $Ax \leq b$ is negative. So, the objective is $b^Ty$ with $y\leq 0$.

To cast that linear problem in convex optimization form, you get $g_i(x) = Ax - b \leq 0$. The dual objective has a term $(Ax-b)^T \lambda$ with $\lambda \geq 0$. Now $x$ will be such that the term with $(Ax)^T\lambda$ cancels with another term, so you will end up with $-b^T\lambda$ with $\lambda \geq 0$.

As you can see, both problems are identical with $y = -\lambda$.